# JS Charts Library

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, linechart

i have to implement a line chart that has many elements to track. I know that there are many libraries, and for now i use highcharts.
The problem is that i pass 12 milestones for the horizontal line, but pass only 3 values. The desired behavior is to draw all of the milestones and draw the line only for those, for who i have passed a value. In the moment it shows only the milestones, for which i have passed a value.

Here is an example:
...

```
    xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
```

...

```
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        marker: {
            symbol: 'square'
        },
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 13.9, 9.6]

    },
```

When supplying less number of data, than the number of xAxis elements, not all of the xAxis elements are show on the chart. I want all of them to show on the chart and the cart line to be drawn only for the xAxis elements for which it has data.

Do you know how i can do that with highcharts, or do you know a library that can do the work.
Thank you for the time.

Regards,
Goergi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i have understood you correctly then you want to have all the categories displayed but their lines to be drawn as you give their data. There is an easy to way to do this in highcharts if you pass the value 'null' for all the milestones you dont want to draw the line for! the array will have 12 values but if you have only three values then first three will be those values and rest null, also you can map them with the categories as well, like give the values at the category number of the array!

```
series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]

        }]
```

Later on you can update the series as you keep on getting the values through

```
chart.series[0].update: [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 75, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]

            }]
```

See the working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xd7k534h/1/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I didn`t explain correctly. See the edit on the question.

Comment: Now that your question is clear, my answer does exactly what you asked for, see the working fiddle and don't forget to mark it as correct answer (:

Comment: you should mark the answer correct if it served your purpose.

Comment: This is about a line chart, so setting them to 0 will not be a good idea. It will confuse the chart.

Comment: sorry didn't notice you need a line chart not column, here is your line chart.. http://jsfiddle.net/xd7k534h/1/

Comment: Also updated the answer which is hopefully the correct answer now, if there is still something not right, let me know (: